# How to use Orc.SystemInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, catel

I downloaded via nuget the package Orc.SystemInfo ([Orc.SystemInfo](https://github.com/WildGums/Orc.SystemInfo)). I managed to display some SystemInfoElements as a list. However no name is provided (name in List is null). I think there is a problem with the LanguageService. I already googled for this problem but I was unable to find a solution.

Here is my code so far (Linq-Pad)

```
void Main()
    {
        var service  = new Orc.SystemInfo.WindowsManagementInformationService();
        var dotnet = new Orc.SystemInfo.DotNetFrameworkService();
        var db = new Orc.SystemInfo.DbProvidersService();
        ILanguageService  lang = new Catel.Services.LanguageService();
        var info = new Orc.SystemInfo.SystemInfoService(service, dotnet, lang, db);
        var infoList = info.GetSystemInfo();
        infoList.Dump();
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply resolve the `ISystemInfo` service using the `ServiceLocator` and all should be taken care of for you.

Comment: Oh boy...Sometimes its so easy... Great, thank you for your help!